# IE8 is choking on the utf8 field when doing Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Using Lazybox in a Rails app to load a form over Ajax. new.js.erb looks like this:

```
$.lazybox('<%=j render "form" %>', {closeImg: true, speed: 100, klass: 'po_lazybox' });
```

and in _form.html.erb the form is being generated with a typical:

```
<%= form_for(@invoice, :remote => @is_remote) do |f| %>
```

FF, Safari, Chrome are fine with this but IE8 won't display the form in the lazybox. It seems to be related to the hidden "utf8" field because if I paste in the rendered form's HTML, minus that field, everything works.

The JS console in IE8 doesn't give any errors, just quietly displays a blank lazybox. IE8 will display the form as a plain html page, i.e. if I go to /invoices/new, everything is fine.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't the form field. The DOM content of the AJAX response started with a blank line, and IE8 has a problem with *that.* When I copied the HTML to tinker with it I must have removed the blank line.

I feel stupid but also mad at IE. I thought choking on blank lines went out of style with Ultrix.